# ExtJS 5 Combobox in a form

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5

I have a question.
When I open the combo box, the list is always transparent, that I see the elements behind it.
What can one do against?

The form will be open in a new window, wenn a Button was klicked.

The code of the Combobox:

```
{
  xtype: 'combo',
  fieldLabel: 'Material',
  store: material,
  queryMode: 'local',
  displayField: 'name',
  valueField: 'abbr',
  editable: false,
  labelWidth: 150,
  width: 300
}
```

http://abload.de/img/extjs5obqid.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run:

```
sencha app refresh
```

if it does not help:

```
sencha ant sass
```

if it does not help:

```
sencha app build
```